# How to hide and show the input element conditionally while input onchange trigger in vueJs

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, dom

I am using v-form-builder from https://github.com/sethsandaru/vue-form-builder .

I am trying to show and hide the fields & sections of the forms depending upon the business logic. I am able to hide the fields by applying additionalContainerClass “d-block”. But by doing so, other fields which had the values visible, they also goes blank.

To achieve this, I have used the following call-backs of vueJs.

```js
mounted() {
  //check the fields to hide
  // hide the fields found by applying using the following code
  this.formData.sections[action.field_section_id].additionalContainerClass = "d-block"
}
```

Now, as soon as the class of “d-block” is added to the field_section, other fields which had the values inserted, gets blank. Here is the video recording of the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztF22iGOW0msR3MAfG13qmgn7zo-4jh_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not answering the question but I do recommend not using an archived repo because you will not get any updates/bug fixes. Which may be quite annoying soon enough.

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice.
We had thought about it earlier but couldn't find any other library apart from this which fulfills our needs.